# Nginx: Limiting number of connections for all content types with exceptions

Tags: nginx, configuration-management, limitations, connlimit

I'm limiting number of simultaneous connections from one $remote_user to n using conn_limit
It works like a charm.
However, I will be thrilled to find a way to add exceptions to this. 
I want user to be able to get *.jpg and *.sql files in as many connections as she wants but still limit *.zip files to just one connection per user.
I've been trying to find a solution in nginx docs for a while now without any success.
Please point me in a right direction.

My config at the moment:

```
limit_conn_zone $remote_user zone=limit:10m;

   server {
    location /source {
      root /home/frog/source/;
      auth_basic "Login";
      auth_basic_user_file /home/frog/.htpasswd;
      limit_conn limit 5;
     }
```

Comment: Show you config. In general putting `*.zip` in separate location should work.

Comment: How would I put *.zip in separate location? I think that blanket limit_conn will override it anyhow. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work

```
location /source {
  root /home/frog/source/;
  auth_basic "Login";
  auth_basic_user_file /home/frog/.htpasswd;

  location ~ "\.zip$" {
    limit_conn limit 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! What do I need to do if there's more than one type? If I want to do the same for *.rar as well?

Comment: location ~ "\.(zip|rar|gz)$" Right?